# how to get only data by object id from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

can someone help me with some code to get data from array based on the id, i've an array with item detail and i only want to return all the prices from the array. here is my array:`var prod = [

```
{
"id": "282",
"product_id": "152737",
"sku": "b175a9ea5f4d9b4766e74079c2bec8",
"prod_name": "PnP Baby Marrows 1kg",
"vendor": "Pick n Pay",
"price": "40.69",
"order_qty": "1"
},
{
"id": "283",
"product_id": "155565",
"sku": "414a1c04ce7fe72269e116d3dd95d3",
"prod_name": "PnP UHT Low Fat Milk 1 Litre x6",
"vendor": "Pick n Pay",
"price": "65.99",
"order_qty": "3"
},
{
"id": "284",
"product_id": "153895",
"sku": "769fca303aa745a43412af20c29e48",
"prod_name": "Plush Dark Furniture Oil 300Ml",
"vendor": "Pick n Pay",
"price": "26.39",
"order_qty": "2"
},
{
"id": "285",
"product_id": "148155",
"sku": "2477f9462d50d0e7b40631c1a347b2",
"prod_name": "Pnp Chicken 4 Thighs And 4 Drumsticks",
"vendor": "Pick n Pay",
"price": "34.86",
"order_qty": "1"
}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal my expected out is the prices only eg: 34.86, 26.39

Comment: Then filter and map chained together

Comment: @joe your question says `to get data from array based on the id` so where does it needed?

Comment: https://medium.com/@joomiguelcunha/learn-map-filter-and-reduce-in-javascript-ea59009593c4

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see a) that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and b) used a [mcve] to narrow down the problem. Asking SO to do all the work for you doesn't help you or us. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `map` method (by passing a `callback` provided function which is applied for every item from your given array) in combination with *destructuring*.

```js
let arr = [{ "id": "282", "product_id": "152737", "sku": "b175a9ea5f4d9b4766e74079c2bec8", "prod_name": "PnP Baby Marrows 1kg", "vendor": "Pick n Pay", "price": "40.69", "order_qty": "1" }, { "id": "283", "product_id": "155565", "sku": "414a1c04ce7fe72269e116d3dd95d3", "prod_name": "PnP UHT Low Fat Milk 1 Litre x6", "vendor": "Pick n Pay", "price": "65.99", "order_qty": "3" }, { "id": "284", "product_id": "153895", "sku": "769fca303aa745a43412af20c29e48", "prod_name": "Plush Dark Furniture Oil 300Ml", "vendor": "Pick n Pay", "price": "26.39", "order_qty": "2" }, { "id": "285", "product_id": "148155", "sku": "2477f9462d50d0e7b40631c1a347b2", "prod_name": "Pnp Chicken 4 Thighs And 4 Drumsticks", "vendor": "Pick n Pay", "price": "34.86", "order_qty": "1" } ]

let prices = arr.map(({price}) => price);
console.log(prices);
```

Comment: I think you meant _destructuring_ :)

Comment: @Andy, yes, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use array filter to do that.

```js
var prod = [
  {
    "id": "282",
    "product_id": "152737",
    "sku": "b175a9ea5f4d9b4766e74079c2bec8",
    "prod_name": "PnP Baby Marrows 1kg",
    "vendor": "Pick n Pay",
    "price": "40.69",
    "order_qty": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "283",
    "product_id": "155565",
    "sku": "414a1c04ce7fe72269e116d3dd95d3",
    "prod_name": "PnP UHT Low Fat Milk 1 Litre x6",
    "vendor": "Pick n Pay",
    "price": "65.99",
    "order_qty": "3"
  },
  {
    "id": "284",
    "product_id": "153895",
    "sku": "769fca303aa745a43412af20c29e48",
    "prod_name": "Plush Dark Furniture Oil 300Ml",
    "vendor": "Pick n Pay",
    "price": "26.39",
    "order_qty": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "285",
    "product_id": "148155",
    "sku": "2477f9462d50d0e7b40631c1a347b2",
    "prod_name": "Pnp Chicken 4 Thighs And 4 Drumsticks",
    "vendor": "Pick n Pay",
    "price": "34.86",
    "order_qty": "1"
  }
]

const getData = (id) => { 
 return prod.filter( (f) => { return f.id === id });
}

console.log(getData("284"));
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you.

```
var prod = [
{
"id": "282",
"product_id": "152737",
"sku": "b175a9ea5f4d9b4766e74079c2bec8",
"prod_name": "PnP Baby Marrows 1kg",
"vendor": "Pick n Pay",
"price": "40.69",
"order_qty": "1"
 },
 {
"id": "283",
"product_id": "155565",
"sku": "414a1c04ce7fe72269e116d3dd95d3",
"prod_name": "PnP UHT Low Fat Milk 1 Litre x6",
"vendor": "Pick n Pay",
"price": "65.99",
"order_qty": "3"
},
{
"id": "284",
"product_id": "153895",
"sku": "769fca303aa745a43412af20c29e48",
"prod_name": "Plush Dark Furniture Oil 300Ml",
"vendor": "Pick n Pay",
"price": "26.39",
"order_qty": "2"
},
{
"id": "285",
"product_id": "148155",
"sku": "2477f9462d50d0e7b40631c1a347b2",
"prod_name": "Pnp Chicken 4 Thighs And 4 Drumsticks",
"vendor": "Pick n Pay",
"price": "34.86",
"order_qty": "1"
}
]
var a=[];
prod.forEach((item=>{a.push(item.price)}));

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var prod = [
{
"id": "282",
"product_id": "152737",
"sku": "b175a9ea5f4d9b4766e74079c2bec8",
"prod_name": "PnP Baby Marrows 1kg",
"vendor": "Pick n Pay",
"price": "40.69",
"order_qty": "1"
},
{
"id": "283",
"product_id": "155565",
"sku": "414a1c04ce7fe72269e116d3dd95d3",
"prod_name": "PnP UHT Low Fat Milk 1 Litre x6",
"vendor": "Pick n Pay",
"price": "65.99",
"order_qty": "3"
},
{
"id": "284",
"product_id": "153895",
"sku": "769fca303aa745a43412af20c29e48",
"prod_name": "Plush Dark Furniture Oil 300Ml",
"vendor": "Pick n Pay",
"price": "26.39",
"order_qty": "2"
}
]

let res = prod.map(item => item.price);
console.log(res);
```

This returns just the price but in an array using map function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which will create a new array, you can use es6 syntax

see the below code

```js
var data = [
  {
    "id": "282",
    "product_id": "152737",
    "sku": "b175a9ea5f4d9b4766e74079c2bec8",
    "prod_name": "PnP Baby Marrows 1kg",
    "vendor": "Pick n Pay",
    "price": "40.69",
    "order_qty": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "283",
    "product_id": "155565",
    "sku": "414a1c04ce7fe72269e116d3dd95d3",
    "prod_name": "PnP UHT Low Fat Milk 1 Litre x6",
    "vendor": "Pick n Pay",
    "price": "65.99",
    "order_qty": "3"
  },
  {
    "id": "284",
    "product_id": "153895",
    "sku": "769fca303aa745a43412af20c29e48",
    "prod_name": "Plush Dark Furniture Oil 300Ml",
    "vendor": "Pick n Pay",
    "price": "26.39",
    "order_qty": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "285",
    "product_id": "148155",
    "sku": "2477f9462d50d0e7b40631c1a347b2",
    "prod_name": "Pnp Chicken 4 Thighs And 4 Drumsticks",
    "vendor": "Pick n Pay",
    "price": "34.86",
    "order_qty": "1"
  }
]


// es6
var pricesES6 = data.map(o => o.price)

// vanilla js
var pricesVJS = data.map(function(o){
  return o.price
})

console.log("prices using es6 =>", pricesES6)

console.log("prices using prices vanilla js ", pricesVJS )
```